# How to set border on recyclerview items which move with animation from item to that item which have focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, border, android-animation

How I can create border on recylerview items which move from item to another item which have focus with animation like netflix tv app

Comment: are you taking about shared element transition ? not all people know or use netflix tv app please provide more inforamtion.

Comment: that is a like sliding animation for example like sliding tablayout